# Reviews of deleted questions affect reputation but help centre doesn't mention that

Tags: support, review, deleted-questions, help-center

I was investigating a change in my reputation; I got -4 points but it doesn't show up in my reputation summary on my User page.  The more detailed daily view tells me that I lost the points due to someone else's post being deleted; I had reviewed the post.

At first I was confused by this, since -4 isn't a listed amount that can be gained or lost.  I trawled through my reputation history and eventually found the corresponding post, I had my answer: I had edited the question twice and both edits had been accepted.  So the -4 is rebalancing that.  All good.

So: should this way of losing reputation be more explicitly listed in the "What is Reputation" [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)?  Currently it says

> If a user reverses a vote, the corresponding reputation loss or gain will be reversed as well.

Obviously the intention here is the same as in my case.  I just don't think that it's apparent that reputation changes due to a particular question (or answer, I'm guessing) can be lost if the question or answer is deleted.  It's logical that they should be, it's just not apparent.

Comment: Go to your reputation page and check "show removed posts" at the bottom. And see the actual reason.

Comment: This isn't about my post.  It's about a review I did on someone else's post.  So I don't have a removed post to show on that page.

Comment: What does "review on a single now-deleted post" mean? What, exactly, does your reputation report say?